# Group 2 and 2 values together in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

Lets say we have a query

```
SELECT recordType,SUM(amount) FROM records GROUP BY recordType
```

**Output**

```
1: 50
2: 100
3: 150
4: 200
```

We have 4 different record types which are 1,2,3 and 4. The above query will obviously return values grouped for those 4 types. How can I adjust the query to show grouping based on their paired grouping. Like return the result of recordType 1 and recordType 2 in one row, and for 3 and 4 in second row.

**Expected Output**

```
Group 1: 150
Group 2: 350
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is doing the grouping correctly, the other part is getting the names of the groups.

If you really have the numbers in question, you can do:

```
select concat('Group ', cast((recordType - 1)/2 as int)), count(*)
from records r
group by cast((recordType - 1)/2 as int)
```

If the values are actually not so arithmetically amenable, then a variable is possibly the simplest method:

```
select concat('Group ', @rn := @rn + 1), count(*)
from records r cross join (select @rn := 0) const
group by (case when type in (1, 2) then 1
               when type in (3, 4) then 2
          end)
```

Answer (score 2):

> Like return the result of recordType 1 and recordType 2 in one row, and for 3 and 4 in second row.

You could do this with a case statement. It won't perform very well, but it'll work. Depending on your actual values, the final query could look something like this:

```
group by case
         when type in(1, 2) then 1
         when type in(3, 4) then 2
         when ...
         else ...
         end
```